# How to search a specific item of a column in ListView?

Tags: vb.net

In my Listview there are 4 columns and there is a TextBox. How to let user to search a string in second column of the Listview?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function getListItemByName(query As String) As ListViewItem

For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lst.Items

  If lvi.Text.Equals(query) Then Return lvi

  For Each si As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In lvi.SubItems

  If si.Text.Equals(query) Then Return lvi

  Next

Next

Return Nothing

End Function
```

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237883-search-for-an-item-in-listview/

Comment: How would you go about search the first column only ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use LINQ:

```
Public Function SearchLV(lv As ListView, SearchString As String, Colmn As Integer) As List(Of ListViewItem)
    SearchLV = (From item In lv.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem)()
            Where item.SubItems(Colmn).Text = SearchString
            Select item).ToList
    If SearchLV.Count = 0 Then
        SearchLV.Add(New ListViewItem("Your search returned no results"))
    End If
End Function
```

This function will return a list of listview items that match the search term in a specific column.  The colmn argument is the zero based index of the column.  If no items are found the first item in the list will contain that message.

to retrieve the items simply iterate through the list:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim searchstring As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim searchlist As List(Of ListViewItem) = Search(ListView1, searchstring, 2)
    Dim mssage As String = ""
    For Each item In searchlist
        For Each subitem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
            mssage += subitem.Text + "-"
        Next
        mssage = mssage.Substring(0, mssage.Length - 1) + vbNewLine
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(mssage)
End Sub
```

If you want a partial word search change:

```
Where item.SubItems(Colmn).Text = SearchString
```

to:

```
Where item.SubItems(Colmn).Text.Contains(SearchString)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me it's easy to understand and easy to modify.
With this you can search specifified rows in listview.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click       

   For Each info As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

                    Dim NameCheck As String = 0
                    Dim SurnameCheck As String = 0
                    Dim IDCheck As String = 0

                    NameCheck = info.Text
                    SurnameCheck = info.SubItems(1).Text
                    IDCheck = info.SubItems(2).Text

                    If NameCheck = TextBox1.Text Then
                        If SurnameCheck = TextBox2.Text Then
                            If IDCheck = TextBox3.Text Then

                                MessageBox.Show("User is already in database!!!", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                                GoTo ErrorReturn 'execute difference piece of code

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
```